# Deleting shortcuts in Windows using Python

Tags: python, batch-file

I have a batch file **abc.bat** which is used to run a Python script **xyz.py**

**abc.bat** should run at startup and therefore has a shortcut in *C:\Users\abhishek.roy\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup*

**abc.bat** :

```
@echo off
python xyz.py
```

**xyz.py** :

```
import datetime
import os

if int(str((datetime.date.now() - datetime.date(2017,12,11))).split()[0]) <= 15
    # Do something
else:
    # Delete the shortcut from the startup folder
    # Need code here
```

The Python program should run for 15 days and after 15 days it should delete the shortcut from the Startup folder so that **abc.bat** stops running at startup. I have been trying 
`os.remove("C:\Users\abhishek.roy\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\abc.bat")` but it gives a **FileNotFoundError**.

Please note that I do not want to delete the original **abc.bat**. I only want to delete the shortcut from the Startup folder.I would like to request any possible solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is the *shortcut* of batch file, not the file itself, just change `.bat` in `os.remove()` to `.lnk`.

Comment: 1) What is the name of shortcut at startup? 2) Is there that shortcut in your startup now?

Comment: 1) The name of the shortcut is "abc.bat - Shortcut "
2) Yes, its still there

Comment: The Windows graphical shell always hides the .lnk extension of shortcuts. The name is actually "abc.bat - Shortcut.lnk".